# Facebook sign-in in iOS fails when sign in through facebook app, it's working if the facebook app not installed in the device

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

***Facebook sign-in is working when the device does not have a Facebook app.***

- Click on the Facebook icon
- Safari opens enter FB user name and pass
- Got access token and complete the process

***Facebook sign-in Fails when the process went through the Facebook app.***

- Click on the Facebook icon
- Safari opens and asks permission for opening the Facebook app
- Facebook open and press continue login after that return to the parent app
- In delegate method access token is nil

  ```
       func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {

       if let token = AccessToken.current,
           !token.isExpired {
           // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
           let req = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name,last_name,first_name,gender,picture.type(large)"], tokenString: token.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: HTTPMethod(rawValue: "GET"))
           req.start { (connection, result, error) in

               if(error == nil) {
                   print("result \(String(describing: result))")
                   if let dict = result as? [String : Any] {
                       self.signupModel = self.createSignupModelFromFB(user: dict)
                       self.checkEmailAvailibility()
                   }
               } else {
                   print("error \(String(describing: error))")
               }
           }
       }

       let loginManager = LoginManager()
       loginManager.logOut()  }
  ```

iOS version: 13
Xcode version: 11

Answer (score 0):

Are you try alredy to remove this lines or comment?

let loginManager = LoginManager()
loginManager.logOut()

maybe its that the problem